# Error with Ajax extension in Local IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I have configured my *IIS* in *Windows 7*. and hosted the site which is running fine.

But it now shows the error as follows

> Server Error in '/' Application. The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1'
>   requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear
>   before any controls that need it. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The control with
>   ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The
>   ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

I have installed *Ajax 1.0*. What would be the reason for the Error.. 
I stuck with this.

Comment: Have you defined a ScriptManager anywhere?

Comment: yes.. it is running fine in server

Answer (score 0):

your scriptmanager should be placed before updatepanel in aspx page inside form tag.
because ajax updatepanel requires Scriptmanager which you can find in your toolbox.

Comment: Yes it is been placed so. the problem is when i Locally configured IIS and hosted it in the local PC. The application is running fine on the remote server.

Comment: then it should work or can you show us your code which you written in your updatepanel

Comment: application uses many update pannels.. 
Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
[InvalidOperationException: The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.]
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.get_ScriptManager() +364889

Comment: just show us your code where scriptmanager is placed. and if application uses many updatepanel then place scriptmanager in site master.aspx

Comment: <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
<cc1:tabcontainer id="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width="100%" activetabindex="2" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged"><cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1"><HeaderTemplate>

Comment: is there any additional config do i have to do with iis .. or am i missing any installations.

Comment: no there isn't, this error occurs if scriptmanager is not in your page & if you are using ajax extensions or controls..